# Add item to list using button

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, sharepoint-online, client-object-model, office-365

I try to create button that will be add item to the list. Unfortunately I do somethings wrong. My programming skill's are at beginner level.
I have list "List" with only one field Title (for test) - at default it will be User and Date.

Code that I have use to create item:

```
function postSurvey()
{
           var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
           var myWeb = context.get_web();
           var myList = myWeb.get_lists().getByTitle('List');
           var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
           var listItem = myList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
           listItem.set_item("Title", Title.value);
           listItem.update();

           context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, AddNewEmployeeSuccess),Function.createDelegate(this, AddNewEmployeeFail));

function AddNewEmployeeFail(sender, args)
{
  alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
function AddNewEmployeeSuccess(sender, args)
{
  alert('Item created: ' + listItem.get_id());
}
}
```

Script:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="../SitePages/AddingNewUser.js"></script>
```

Button def.:

```
<tr>
  <td><input type='text' id='Title'/></td>  
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><button type="button" id="btnAddCar" onclick="postSurvey()">Add</button></td>
</tr>
```

After click on Button I don't have **AddNewEmployeeFail** message - just only "**Fail**" pop-up.

[image: Fail alert]

I try this samples without any results:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185011(v=office.14).aspx
http://digsharepoint.blogspot.com/2012/03/javascript-front-end-to-start.html
http://ishaalan.wordpress.com/2010/05/23/adding-an-item-to-a-sharepoint-list-using-javascript/  - with this article I can't find SP.js and I don't know where to put this library.

I'm working on SharePoint Online 2010 (on 2013 will some difference's in code?) .

Comment: Does adding context.load(listItem); after .update() help?

Comment: Robert, I have add context.load(listItem) like you suggest - without any positive result. Still have "Fail".

Comment: what stacktrace error message you get?

Comment: Varun, how I can get error messager detail? I have only popup "Fail"

Answer (score 1):

### Setting `Title` value

The line:

```
listItem.set_item("Title", Title.name);
```

is used for setting Title column from `Title.name` object.

Are you using something like this to initialize Title object?

```
var Title = {};
Title.name = $('#title').val();
```

### Ensure sp.js library is loaded

In order to ensure that sp.js is loaded, change  function your function to

```
function postSurvey()
{
   SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){
      var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
      //your remaining code goes here...  
   }, 'sp.js');
}
```

Comment: Stil fail. I have change code, like you says.

Comment: Or, how I can call out Workflow that will add item to the list?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
listItem.update();

context.load(listItem);

           context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, AddNewEmployeeSuccess),Function.createDelegate(this, AddNewEmployeeFail));
```